# Сделать программу на PHP, которая будет выводить свой исходный код

Tags: php

Написать программу на PHP, которая будет выводить свой исходный код, будучи запущенной через веб-сервер. Функции `highlight_string`, `highlight_file`, `show_source` и константу `__FILE__` использовать запрещено!

Примечание: программа НЕ должна быть квайном.

Как бы вы решали такое задание?
В первую очередь интересует именно идея (впрочем, от кода тоже не откажусь :))

Comment: А в чем именно у вас проблема? Или вы просто хотите получить решение вашей задачи?

Comment: Достаточно просто сказать как ее решали бы вы.Какой-либо код выкладывать совершенно не обязательно

Comment: @Vlad, я бы решал именно так, как написано в условии. я считаю, что это полностью отвечает на текущую редакцию вашего вопроса, и, скорее всего, вы спрашиваете совсем о другом. напишите, пожалуйста, в чём именно состоит ваш вопрос, отредактировав его с помощью кнопки [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: тут просто россыпь способов, как получить адрес файла в обход `__FILE__`, начиная с `__DIR__` и кончая `get_included_files()`

Comment: Все-таки определитесь, что именно вы пробовали сделать и что именно не получается и напишите в тексте вопроса. Здесь сильно не любят просьбы сделать что-то за вас. Надеюсь на понимание

Comment: У вас дыра в вопросе. Квайн по определению -- программа, выводящая свой исходный код.

Comment: @D-side, "При этом программы, использующие внешние данные (чтение текста программы из файла, ввод его с клавиатуры и так далее), куайнами не считаются." - википедия.

Comment: @Qwertiy если имелось в виду это, то вообще непонятно, в чём проблема.